# Get Inserted id with Spring JDBCTemplate development different then GAE

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-sql

I'm using gwt, Spring and mysql.  The following function inserts a row into the table Users and returns the inserted "Id".  In development mode this works as described.

```
 public int insert(String username, String emailAddress){

    String query = "INSERT INTO Users " +
            "(UserName, EmailAddress) VALUES " +
            "(:username, :emailAddress); ";

    SqlParameterSource namedParameters =
            new MapSqlParameterSource("username",  username)
            .addValue("emailAddress", emailAddress);

    // Insert
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, namedParameters, keyHolder, new String[]{"Id"});

    Number id = keyHolder.getKey();

    return id.intValue();

}
```

When I upload this to GAE and use google Cloud sql, the record gets inserted but the "Id" is not returned.  I get the following error:

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: The generated key is not of a supported numeric type. Unable to cast [java.lang.String] to [java.lang.Number]

Any Suggestions,

Thanks.

Based on the comments below I've added my Table Definition:

> CREATE TABLE `Users` (
>     `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User Id',
>     `Username` varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Username used for login',
>     `EmailAddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Email Address of the user',
>     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
>     UNIQUE KEY `Code` (`Username`),
>     UNIQUE KEY `Code` (`EmailAddress`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

When I run ALTER TABLE `Users` MODIFY COLUMN `Id` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto Id';

I get the error ERROR 1063 (42000): Incorrect column specifier for column 'Id'.  Which says that a varchar cannot auto_increment.  Also I think GAE does not allow triggers in the mysql so I'm not sure how to accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: Your id must be of type varchar.

Comment: check your table and datatype of id.agree with benjamin id is of type varchar.

Comment: Thank you benjamin.d and Purnendu.  I've appended my table definition because I have a conflict if I change the Id to Varchar.  Cheers

Comment: Try out the GeneratedKeyHolder usage approaches described [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder).

Comment: Was the `GeneratedKeyHolder` suggested helpful.  Have you found a solution to this issue.  If so, please post as a self-answer.

Comment: I ended up doing something else.  I never did try the GeneratedKeyHolder approach.  If it does work let me know, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: The steps needed to reproduce the issue are not clear given the amount of variables in all the code and configuration which surrounds the snippet given, so it's not really likely that anybody can test the same issue. Feel free to provide instructions or more code, or else this should close as "too broad".

Comment: Given that the issue was only observed on your system, and it's not given that someone writing similar code will reproduce the problem, this should be closed as "too broad", since OP has apparently moved on without clarifying what solution ("I ended up doing something else") actually applied.